# latest full half hour as per the clock time data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, getdate

I trying to fetch data for the latest full half hour as per the clock time.

for example if getdate() return me '2016-11-14 10:14:25.567' , i want data from '2016-11-14 09:30:00.000' to '2016-11-14 10:00:00.000'

Comment: dateadd(minute, -30, getdate())?

Comment: So you want it to show the half hour (as per clock time) in which the getdate() falls?

Comment: `Where yourcolumn >= dateadd(minute, -30, getdate())`

Comment: The way i read the question is that he doesn't want just the latest 30 minutes, he wants the latest full half hour as per the clock time.

Comment: @Rich - yes I agree - it is incorrectly assigned as duplicate - the question is much trickier than the one classed as duplicate - ~A golden rule has been broken here - because he DID give us an exact example of what he wanted

Comment: how about 'datediff(minute,0,getdate()) / 30 =  datediff(minute,0,YourField) / 30'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this;

```
DECLARE @DateVariable datetime; SET @DateVariable = GETDATE()

SELECT
    @DateVariable Current_DateTime
    ,DATEADD(mi,-30, CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(@DateVariable AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) ) From_Time
    ,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST(@DateVariable AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) To_Time
```

Where the date variable is now (2016-11-14 16:26:52) it will give you the last full half hour

The result will look like this;

```
Current_DateTime            From_Time               To_Time
2016-11-14 16:26:52.073     2016-11-14 15:30:00     2016-11-14 16:00:00
```

Comment: that's what i am trying to do. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateADD(mi, -30, getdate())`